# Specifying the active screen for fullscreen KDE applications

Tags: multiple-monitors, kde, fullscreen

I want to script-start a fullscreen krdc connection on my primary monitor.  However, the only control I seem to have over the active screen is the "Active screen follows mouse" option -- which I like, but which isn't helpful for scripts.

The --geometry option doesn't help.

Since I can't trust the active screen, is there another way (EG, environment, kstart) to specify which screen is active for a specific application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set manual overrides for things using the Window Rules feature of KDE. The easiest way is to open the program then right click it's title bar and select <kbd>More Actions</kbd> then <kbd>Special Application Settings</kbd> then adjust the `Screen` setting to `Force` and specify the number of the screen, I believe `1` is the primary and `2` would be your secondary monitor.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, very useful!  I had no idea all that kwin stuff existed -- the window matching tab even made it possible to restrict the rule to this specific window.